# stop application if pushed thread had exception in Perl

Tags: r, perl, parallel-processing

I have aplication which runs in parallel mode. Jobs are runing using threads with implmented subroutine. Subroutine "worker3" have three argumens, one parameter and two path for files.
This subroutine execute R script using system commands.

```
if ($ENV{"model"} eq "alaef_cy40_5km"){

      sub worker3 {
      my $parameter2 = $_[0];
       print $parameter2, "\n";
      $ENV{"grb_path"} = $models{$model}{"grb"}{"path"}{$parameter2};
      $ENV{"grb_file"} = $models{$model}{"grb"}{"file"}{$parameter2};
      print"FROM sub:", "\n";
      print $ENV{"grb_path"}, "\n";
      print $ENV{"grb_file"}, "\n";
      say "Job  Started\n";
      system("Rscript $root/read_ALAEF.R @_ ");

 
}
      
      for my $param( 'T2m','RH2m'){
      push @threads, my $thr1=threads ->create('worker3', $param ,$ENV{"grb_file"},$ENV{"grb_path"})

      }

      $_->join() for threads->list();
     
   }
```

Problem is when R script finish with Execution halted, application final status is ok. What i need is when R script finished with error, the whole program needs to be stopped.
So, if one thread fails, application needs to stops, and display error.

This is output:

```
T2m
FROM sub:
/data/nwp/products/a-laef_stream
A-LAEF_mem_{MBR2}_{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HH}_surface.grb
Job  Started

RH2m
FROM sub:
/data/nwp/products/a-laef_stream
A-LAEF_mem_{MBR2}_{YYYY}{MM}{DD}{HH}_surface.grb
Job  Started

-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.1 --
v ggplot2 3.3.5     v purrr   0.3.4
v tibble  3.1.6     v dplyr   1.0.7
v tidyr   1.1.4     v stringr 1.4.0
v readr   2.1.0     v forcats 0.5.1
-- Attaching packages --------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.3.1 --
v ggplot2 3.3.5     v purrr   0.3.4
v tibble  3.1.6     v dplyr   1.0.7
v tidyr   1.1.4     v stringr 1.4.0
v readr   2.1.0     v forcats 0.5.1
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
here() starts at /work/users/p6095/2022-02-19_00/harp.119
Loading required package: harpIO

Attaching package: 'harpIO'

The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':

    accumulate

Loading required package: harpPoint
Loading required package: harpVis
Loading required package: shiny
-- Conflicts ------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
here() starts at /work/users/p6095/2022-02-19_00/harp.119
Loading required package: harpIO

Attaching package: 'harpIO'

The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':

    accumulate

Loading required package: harpPoint
Loading required package: harpVis
Loading required package: shiny
Loading required package: harpSpatial
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"
'4'"
Execution halted
Loading required package: harpSpatial
Error: unexpected string constant in:
"
'4'"
Execution halted

----------------------------------------------------
Application finished OK at: 21-02-2022  15:46:11 UTC
----------------------------------------------------
```

As you see, it shows that application finished OK, no matter if is the error inside R code. I need this : if pushed thread had exception -> stop application perl

Comment: Can you create a minimal but also *runnable* example illustrating your issue ? See [mcve] for more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can stop the main program with a status message if one of the executables run by a given thread fails:

First, I constructed a dummy executable `foo.pl` like this:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($id, $force_fail) = @ARGV;
my $thread1_exit_value = $force_fail ? 2 : 0;
if ($id == 1) {
    sleep 2;
    exit $thread1_exit_value;
}
elsif ($id == 2) {
    sleep 5;
    exit 0;
}
```

Then the main program like this:

```
use v5.20;            # experimental signatures requires perl >= 5.20
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use experimental qw(signatures);
use threads;

{
    my @threads;
    my $force_fail = 1;
    my $start_time = time;
    for (1..2) {
        my $thr = threads->create(
            sub {
                my $res = system "foo.pl", $_, $force_fail; $res
            }
        );
        push @threads, $thr;
    }
    my $fail = 0;
    for my $i (0..$#threads) {
        my $thr = $threads[$i];
        if ($fail) {
            say "detaching thread $i..";
            $thr->detach();
        }
        else {
            say "joining thread $i..";
            my $res = $thr->join();
            if (command_failed($res, $i)) {
                $fail = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    my $total_time = time - $start_time;
    say "Program " . ($fail ? "failed" : "succeeded") . " after $total_time seconds";
}
    
sub command_failed( $res, $id ) {
    if ($res == -1) {
        say "thread $id failed to execute: $!";
        return 1;
    }
    elsif ($res & 127) {
        printf "thread $id died from signal %d\n", $res & 127;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        my $rcode = $res >> 8;
        if ($rcode != 0) {
            say "thread $id exited with return value $rcode";
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When setting `$force_fail = 1` on line 9 of the main script, the output is:

```
joining thread 0..
thread 0 exited with return value 2
detaching thread 1..
Program failed after 2 seconds
```

On the other hand, when setting `$force_fail = 0` the output is:

```
joining thread 0..
joining thread 1..
Program succeeded after 5 seconds
```